# Cannot get persistent logs using KubernetesExecutor with an EFS volume using official airflow helm chart

Tags: airflow, helm3

I see the PVC is bounded to the PV. But when I enable `log.persistence.enabled: true`, the scheduler and webserver keeps crashing because it does not have permission to the logs folder. This is the error when I describe pod:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler'`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of our custom Dockerfile for airflow we set the user as airflow and chown the entire airflow home dir so that these permissions are not an issue. This way the airflow pod itself runs as airflow and any pod spun up using this image by the kubernetes executor is running as airflow.

```
RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
```

Comment: I do have this in the Dockerfile. So the issue is something else.

Comment: Can you share any additional pieces of information? It's possible your chart UID is not translating to the user Airflow or vice versa in the dockerfile. I would try using the UID directly in Dockerfile rather than "airflow". For example, near the end of the Dockerfile add "USER 50000" and then make sure there is the corresponding UID:GID under image in the values file -- uid: 50000 gid: 0